# How to get a generated karaf kar file to be included with a maven assembly?

Tags: java, maven, apache-karaf

Trying to get the maven assembly plugin to include my kar file.

This below works fine with "war" or "jar", but not with "kar".

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <includes>
            <include>${project.groupId}:*:kar:${project.version}</include>
        </includes>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <outputDirectory>karaf/deploy</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the kar file as a dependency in the pom.